# How to use arbitrary text as node name in tikz graph in a simple way?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

I would like to use tikz graph to draw graphs of function calling relations. But I have trouble with function names from C programming language, where underscore is allowed in a function name.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usepackage{shortvrb}
\MakeShortVerb{\|}

\begin{document}
|func_one()| calls |func_two()|:

\tikz \graph {
    "|func_one()|" -> "|func_two()|";
};
\end{document}
```

For the above example, TeX complains

```
Missing $ inserted. }
```

Is there a simple way to let C function name be the name of a tikz graph node without much handling with the function name? In my case, there will be many functions in a calling graph and each name may include multiple underscores. Sigh.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try with `\_`

Comment: @CarLaTeX Thanks for your comments. Since many C function names have underscore, to append a backslash to each underscore is heavy for me. I prefer some way like shortvrb or to make shortvrb to work in graph node.

Comment: OK, I leave the answer to some expert :)

Answer (score 3):

You could just use `\catcode\_=11` before the picture, or if you are happy to use `\scantokens`, you could try using a custom typesetter using the key `/tikz/graphs/typeset`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\def\typesetter{{\catcode`\_=11
\ttfamily\expandafter\scantokens\expandafter{\tikzgraphnodetext}}}
\begin{document}
\tikz\graph [typeset=\typesetter, grow down] {
  "func_one()" -> "func_two()";
};
\end{document}
```

[image]