# tikz-uml can't handle class names containing underscores

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-uml

tikz-uml's `umlinherit` command breaks when passing in names containing underscores, consider:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \umlinterface[x=-2]{a}{}{}

  \umlclass[x=2]{a\_impl}{}{}

  \umlinherit{a\_impl}{a}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This fails to compile: `Package pgf Error: No shape named 'a_impl' is known`. It seems to me that this is clearly a bug, but I've already used `tikz-uml` for several diagrams in my document so I wonder if there is a workaround for this.

Comment: `tikz-uml` is not part of a standard installation!? The only manual I can find is from 2016: https://perso.ensta-paris.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/var/files/doc/tikzumlmanual.pdf Under Installation, it says "Coming soon". To me it looks like a dead project.

Comment: @hpekristiansen: Yes, I'm working on an old document that already uses tikz-uml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the category code of the underscore to 11 or 12 (letter/other) within the `tikzpicture` environment. This means you don't need to escape it. It also means that you cannot use `_` for math subscript anymore, you can use `\sb{}` instead. Moreover it means that you need to use `T1` font encoding otherwise LaTeX does not know how to map `_` to an actual underscore character. Finally it is advised to choose a different font, because Computer Modern has a very low underscore (visibly below the baseline), and Latin Modern has a very wide underscore. In the MWE below I used Palatino.

If you set the catcode within the environment then the change is local so you can use the underscore as normal in the rest of your document.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\catcode`\_=12
  \umlinterface[x=-2]{a}{}{}

  \umlclass[x=2]{a_impl}{$a\sb{1\dots n}$}{}

  \umlinherit{a_impl}{a}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Sources: [How to use arbitrary text as node name in tikz graph in a simple way?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408908/how-to-use-arbitrary-text-as-node-name-in-tikz-graph-in-a-simple-way)

[Is it safe to set underscore to a non-active character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359787/is-it-safe-to-set-underscore-to-a-non-active-character)

[Decrease length of underscore character in normal text (gender_gap)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128814/decrease-length-of-underscore-character-in-normal-text-gender-gap)

Comment: Amazing! Works perfectly.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work anymore. however, because tikz-uml has to be locally installed by the user, an alternative approach is to add ```lang-tex\detokenize{}``` applications to the defines for ```lang-tex \tikzumlClassName```, ```lang-tex \tikzumlClassAttributes```, and ```lang-tex \tikzumlClassOperations```; possibly others, these were the ones in use for what i need to work again.

Comment: @regnirpsj I just tried to compile it again with TeX Live 2022 and that still works, maybe in TL 2023 it broke? I will check again when I have access to that version (if I remember).

Comment: with TeX Live 2022/CVE-2023-32700 under fedora 38 the ```detokenize``` approach doesn't anymore as well. i guess there's no useable uml support for TeX these days

Comment: @regnirpsj I just tried my code above with TeX Live 2023 and that also works - so I'm guessing there is a problem with the way you use the code or with your installation (maybe a different tikz-uml version?)